# How to slice rows in numba CUDA?

Tags: arrays, cuda, numba, memcpy

I am a beginner in Numba. I have difficulty in re-arranging the rows of an array in GPU.

In Numba CPU, for example, this can be done by

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def numba_cpu(A, B, ind):
    for i, t in enumerate(ind):
        B[i, :] = A[t, :]

ind = np.array([3, 2, 0, 1, 4])
A = np.random.rand(5, 3)
B = np.zeros((5, 3))
numba_cpu(A, B, ind)
```

But it does not work with cuda.jit

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np

@cuda.jit
def numba_gpu(A, B, ind):
    for i, t in enumerate(ind):
        B[i, :] = A[t, :]

d_ind = cuda.to_device(np.array([3, 2, 0, 1, 4]))
d_A = cuda.to_device(np.random.rand((5, 3)))
d_B = cuda.to_device(np.zeros((5, 3)))
numba_gpu[16,16](d_A, d_B, d_ind)
```

The program fails with a lot of exceptions, and it says "NRT required but not enabled".

Of course I can use a nested loop to copy entry by entry, but it looks bad because I know the a row is in consecutive memory. Even a C-language-like `memcpy` would be better. But it seems Numba does not support `memcpy`.

Comment: The most efficient way to do this in numba CUDA is to use adjacent threads to copy adjacent elements in a row of `A` to adjacent elements in a row of `B`.  You don't want to use an "ordinary" loop.  numba CUDA supports less than what is supported by ordinary numba, and far less than what is supported in numpy or python.  A list of supported features is [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/cudapysupported.html).  If what you are trying to do is not in that list, it generally won't work.

Comment: Thank you. It is good to know the limitation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I have found a solution myself. What I need is to manipulate Numpy arrays in CUDA device. For this purpose, CuPy is much better than Numba. CuPy supports many Numpy-like operations (including the one in my question) in an efficient and convenient way.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is this the answer to the question "How to slice rows in numba CUDA?
"

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that those slice operators are not supported on the device in Numba. The underlying problem is that slice operation requires an intermediate array construction and the Numba compiler currently can't do that.

There are probably two alternative ways to do this:

1. Use a single thread to copy a row of the data between the source and destination (`numba_gpu1` shown below)
2. Use a single block to copy a row of the data between the source and destination. This can exploit a strided loop design pattern which improves memory coalescing and cache coherency and should perform better at non-trivial sizes (`numba_gpu2` shown below for row major ordered data).

In code this looks something like:

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np

@cuda.jit
def numba_gpu1(A, B, ind):
  idx = cuda.grid(1)
  if idx < len(ind):
    t = ind[idx]
    for k in range(A.shape[1]):
       B[idx, k] = A[t, k]

@cuda.jit
def numba_gpu2(A, B, ind):
  idx = cuda.grid(1)
  if idx < len(ind):
    t = ind[idx]
    k = cuda.threadIdx.y
    while k < A.shape[1]:
       B[idx, k] = A[t, k]
       k += cuda.blockDim.y

def test1():
  d_ind = cuda.to_device(np.array([3, 2, 0, 1, 4], dtype=np.int32))
  d_A = cuda.to_device(np.random.rand(5, 3).astype(np.float32))
  d_B = cuda.to_device(np.zeros((5, 3), dtype=np.float32))

  numba_gpu1[1,32](d_A, d_B, d_ind)

  ind = d_ind.copy_to_host()
  A = d_A.copy_to_host()
  B = d_B.copy_to_host()

  return np.allclose(A[ind],B)

def test2():
  d_ind = cuda.to_device(np.array([3, 2, 0, 1, 4], dtype=np.int32))
  d_A = cuda.to_device(np.random.rand(5, 3).astype(np.float32))
  d_B = cuda.to_device(np.zeros((5, 3), dtype=np.float32))

  numba_gpu2[5,32](d_A, d_B, d_ind)

  ind = d_ind.copy_to_host()
  A = d_A.copy_to_host()
  B = d_B.copy_to_host()

  return np.allclose(A[ind],B)

print("Test 1:", test1())
print("Test 2:", test2())
```

[disclaimer: This code was written in two minutes in Google colab and run once. It needs further code to generalize it to any size and further testing to ensure it works correctly. No warranty implied, use at own risk]

Which version you choose probably depends on the size of the problem you apply it to. I would expect that `numba_gpu2` will be preferred for problems with rows which are many times longer the CUDA warp size, whereas `numba_gpu1` is probably preferable for problems with many short rows. A smart approach would be to have heuristics to select between them depending on the size and shape of the data. Verification and implementation of all of this speculation is left as an exercise for the reader.